# Is there good evidence of sitting being unhealthy?

Tags: public-health

Is there any evidence of sitting causing bad health, or are the statements in the news based on epidemiological studies on correlations only, i.e. people who sit a lot have worse health?

If the answer is "no, all studies are epidemiological", how sure can one be that sitting less actually improves health?

Comment: Marten, can you [edit] your question? This site is about proving or debunking notable claims. Add references to claims in your text, and remove everything trying to explain 'good/bad research'.

Comment: "Risk" is inherently a matter of probabilities. You *never* know for a fact that a risk factor will cause something. Nevertheless, knowing what we know, it would be majorly stupid to start smoking if you currently don't.

Comment: @JanDoggen all posts are community owned, you don't need to ask to permission to edit them.

Comment: @Sklivvz Marten is a new user, I decided to guide him this way rather than do the work myself. Editing out 80% of his text can be consider rude and I don't have the links to claims.

Comment: Alright, I'll restate my question and remove all of the fluff which includes the statements made without references.